# Making TabBarView dynamically in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, tabs, tabbar

### Situation:

I have two lists,`tabsText` and `mainListAllPlantDetailsList1`. 
**tabsText**

```
  List<String> tabsText = ["Top","Outdoor","Indoor", "Seeds", "Flowers"];
```

**mainListAllPlantDetailsList1**

```
List<PlantDetails> mainListAllPlantDetailsList1 = [
    PlantDetails(
      indexNumber: 0,
      category: "flower",
      plantName: "Lamb's Ear",
      price: 147,
      description: "This is the Lamb's Ear flower"
    ),
    PlantDetails(
      indexNumber: 1,
      category: "seeds",
      plantName: "Lotus",
      price: 120,
      description: "This is the lotus seeds"
    ),
    PlantDetails(
      indexNumber: 2,
      category: "indoor",
      plantName: "Hughusi Yoon",
      price: 147,
      description: "This is the Hughusi Yoon indoor"
    ),
    PlantDetails(
      indexNumber: 3,
      category: "outdoor",
      plantName: "lily",
      price: 120,
      description: "This is the lily outdoor"
    ),
  ];
```

### Details:

I have made the TabBar using for loop in the `tabsText` list. Now I am again making the `TabBarView` using for loop and I tried like this

```
tabViewerMaker(){
  List<Widget> tabBarView = List();
  for(var i = 0; i<tabsText.length;i++){
    for( var j =0; j<mainListAllPlantDetailsList1.length;j++){
      if(tabsText[i] == mainListAllPlantDetailsList1[j].ca){
        tabBarView.add(
        Text("We found category"+tabsText[i])
        );
      }
      else{
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I have checked the `tabsText` and `mainListAllPlantDetailsList1`. If the String of particular index of `tabsText` is equal to particular index of `mainListAllPlantDetailsList1` then, generate a widget,
`Text("We found category"+tabsText[i])`
otherwise just continue. And I have made a list of type widget and added all the text widget, but while calling the function `tabViewerMaker` **Why does it give error?**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Container(bg: BoxDecoration(color:
Color(0xffffffff)), constraints: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, h=317.0)):
The getter 'key' was called on null.
```

### Question:

**How can I achieve the desired function using for loop or feel free to give any suggestion?**

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'key' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: key